# Convert System::String^% to std::string&

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr

I have a C++ function which takes a `std::string&` and the string is changed within this function.

I have a CLR function which is passed a `System::String^%`. I want to be able to pass the CLR string tracking reference to the C++ function and have it change accordingly.

So far I have something like this but it seems quite ugly:

```
void test(System::String^% x)
{
    pin_ptr<System::String^> x_ptr = &x;
    std::string x_cpp = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(*x_ptr);
    x_cpp = "qwerty"; //in real code this string is passed to function and changed
    x = gcnew System::String(x_cpp.c_str());
}
```

is there a  more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For the first: Because the `marshal_as` method is declared as taking a `System::String^ const &`, you can't pass a tracking reference directly. (If there's a cast you can do, I can't figure out what it would be.) However, you can copy `x` to a regular local variable, and pass that to `marshal_as`. This eliminates the pin_ptr, which is a good thing.

For the second: Use the same conversion method for the second conversion as the first. Unless you have a special reason to do it differently, `marshal_as` is probably the best way to handle these conversions.

```
void otherFunction(std::string& x_cpp)
{
    x_cpp = "qwerty";
}

void test(System::String^% x)
{
    System::String^ x_not_tracking_ref = x;
    std::string x_cpp = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(x_not_tracking_ref);
    otherFunction(x_cpp);
    x = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(x_cpp);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ foo = "asdfgh";
    Debug::WriteLine(foo);
    test(foo);
    Debug::WriteLine(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
asdfgh
qwerty
```

Comment: Here's another approach: `template<typename T> inline T^ remove_tracking_ref(T^ x) { return x; }` then `marshal_as<std::string>(remove_tracking_ref(x))` but I guess using a local variable is simpler :)

Comment: You can dereference the tracking reference: `msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(%*x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I don't think so.  I would tend to try and release the pin_ptr as soon as possible.  So something like:

```
std::string string_from_string(System::String^% x)
{
    pin_ptr<System::String^> x_ptr = &x;
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(*x_ptr);
}

void test(System::String^% x)
{
    auto x_cpp = string_from_string(x);
    x_cpp = "qwerty";//in real code this string is passed to function and changed
    x = gcnew System::String(x_cpp.c_str());
}
```

(Names and syntax all approximate.  You might want to write a string_from_string in the reverse direction.